# Built Tauri App closes unexpectedly with no errors reading json file

Tags: json, rust, listener, tauri

The app works entirely as expected in the development environment.

I am using tauri to build a screen recording app. When I press a button that is supposed to open a local json file in the project instead of having the expected output the .exe just closes. No errors and no output.

I use a listener for when the button is pressed.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
 const el =  document
    .querySelector("#load_settings_btn_id");
    if(el)
    el
    .addEventListener("click", () => read_data_to_html());
});
```

The read_data_to_html() function just writes data from the json file to the input fields in the html

```
async function read_data_to_html() {
  document.querySelector("#screenshot_saving_dir_data_id").value = await invoke("return_screenshot_output_dir_data");
  document.querySelector("#video_output_dir_data_id").value =  await invoke("return_video_output_dir_data");
  document.querySelector("#video_caching_dir_data_id").value =  await invoke("return_stream_cache_dir_data");
  document.querySelector("#action_replay_data_id").value =await  invoke("return_action_replay_dur_data");
  document.querySelector("#streaming_url_data_id").value = await invoke("return_stream_port_data");
  document.querySelector("#unique_file_name_data_id").value = await invoke("return_unique_file_name_data");
  document.querySelector("#x_offset_data_id").value = await invoke("return_x_offset_data");
  document.querySelector("#y_offest_data_id").value = await invoke("return_y_offset_data");
  document.querySelector("#region_size_x_data_id").value = await invoke("return_video_size_x_data");
  document.querySelector("#region_size_y_data_id").value = await invoke("return_video_size_y_data");
  document.querySelector("#show_region_data_id").checked = await  invoke("return_show_region_data");
  document.querySelector("#framerate_data_id").value =await invoke("return_framerate_data");
  document.querySelector("#microphone_audio_input_id").value = await invoke("return_micropohne_device_data");
  document.querySelector("#desktop_audio_input_id").value =  await invoke("return_desktop_device_data");
//micropohone inputs still need here
}
```

for not making this post extremely long I am only attaching one of the await functions here

```
#[tauri::command]
fn return_framerate_data() -> i32 {
    let _variable_list = {
        let _variable_list = std::fs::read_to_string("./Data/ffmpeg_variables.json").unwrap();
        serde_json::from_str::<FfmpegVariables>(&_variable_list).unwrap()
    };
    return _variable_list.framerate;
}
```

Again the app works exactly as expected in the development environment just when the Event Listener is triggered the entire app closes with no warnings.

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

EDIT: here is the link to my project incase I am missing something here
https://github.com/FizleWit/sabil_shot_3_22

Answer (score 0):

Realized I forgot to add the Paths to my json file in my tauri.conf.json file.
Here is my tauri.conf.json with the path to my json file I hope someone else can be helped from this.

> "tauri": {
> "allowlist": {
> "all": true,
> "shell": {
> "all": true,
> "open": true
> }
> },

```
    "resources": [
    "Data/*"
  ],
```